# Upgrade to Artifact Registry from Container Registry [May 2023]

Tags: android, flutter, google-cloud-platform

I have a Flutter Android App uploaded to PlayStore which is live.

I have recently received an email from Google Cloud (The Google Container Registry Team) that I need to upgrade Upgrade to Artifact Registry from Container Registry

`Container Registry will be phased out, starting May 15, 2024. Please review the options below for how to upgrade your projects to Artifact Registry.Container Registry will be phased out, starting May 15, 2024. Please review the options below for how to upgrade your projects to Artifact Registry.`

**What do you need to do?**

These are the two transition paths we recommend you follow depending on your project’s architecture:

For projects where you use Container Registry:
Consider moving to Artifact Registry. Learn about options to transition to Artifact Registry to prepare for discontinuation of Container Registry.

**My Question**

What I need to do here? I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: I had a similar question for App Engine— https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76275397/migrate-app-engine-standard-away-fromcontainer-registry-for-artifact-regi

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do anything in your current project.

The Container Registry will be phased out on May 15, 2024.

The only projects that is allowed to host the images in Container Registry will be the one in which are only:

1.) The Container Registry API was enabled before May 15, 2024.

2.) Images were pushed to Container Registry.

after May 15, 2024 all projects will be automatically hosted in [Artifact Registry](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs).

In case you are wondering, Artifact Registry extends the capabilities of the Container Registry. For additional information about the [Feature comparison](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/transition/transition-from-gcr#feature-comparison).

Comment: I received the same email but I have a project currently using container registry, we have to do something to migrate right because it says action required?