# Transitioning from Google Container Registry to Google Artifact Registry for Python App Deployment on Google App Engine

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, google-container-registry, google-artifact-registry

We deploy our Python application using Google App Engine in the standard environment. In our continuous integration (CI) process, we rely on a single command, `gcloud app deploy`, which handles all the necessary tasks, including building the Docker image and pushing it to the Google Container Registry before deployment.

However, since Google Container Registry is set to be deprecated soon, we are exploring the option of explicitly configuring Google Artifact Registry to store our Docker images. Is this feasible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Since Google Container Registry is set to be deprecated soon, we are exploring the option of explicitly configuring Google Artifact Registry to store our Docker images. Is this feasible?

I think you might need not to worry about configuring Google Artifact Registry, As stated by `James (Artifact Registry Engineer)` at [Stackoverflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76275711/18265702)

> The announced change does not affect any projects that are currently using Container Registry. Only projects not using Container Registry by May 2024 will be affected and they will automatically use Artifact Registry for App Engine.

However if you want to configure Google Artifact Registry for your app engine application you can follow below steps.

1. [Copy images to Artifact Registry](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/transition/setup-gcr-repo#copy)
2. [Enable Redirection of Traffic to Artifact Registry](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/transition/setup-gcr-repo#redirect-enable)

Complete documentation and prerequisites for this configuration change are available at [Transition to Artifact Registry](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/transition/setup-gcr-repo#copy).

As an additional information for you, Artifact Registry allows you to store Docker container images same like container registry. You can use [docker registry API](http://cloud/artifact-registry/docs/reference/docker-api) as well as regular OnePlatform [Rest](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/reference/rest) and [RPC](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/reference/rpc) APIs.

Artifact Registry implements a Docker protocol so that you can push and pull images directly with Docker clients, including the Docker command-line tool.

**Note:** Artifact Registry does not support Docker chunked uploads. Some container image tools support uploading large container images with either chunked uploads or a single monolithic upload. You must use monolithic uploads when you push container images to Artifact Registry.